# PostgreSQL Function Error

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql

I need some help to solve a problem with my PostgreSQL 9.1 function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COMMISSION_MARGIN(Aiid NUMERIC) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
    DECLARE
           COMISSAO NUMERIC;
           TOTAL_SEM_IMPOSTO NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
            COMISSAO='"SELECT SUM(ILA.QUANTITY) FROM INVOICE_LINE_AGENT AS ILA
                     INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE_LINE AS AIL ON ILA.INVOICE_LINE_ID = AIL.ID
                     INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE AS AI ON AI.ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
                     WHERE AI.ID = Aiid GROUP BY AI.ID"';

            TOTAL_SEM_IMPOSTO='"SELECT SUM(AIL.PRICE_SUBTOTAL) FROM INVOICE_LINE_AGENT AS ILA
                     INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE_LINE AS AIL ON ILA.INVOICE_LINE_ID = AIL.ID
                     INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE AS AI ON AI.ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
                     WHERE AI.ID = Aiid GROUP BY AI.ID"';
            RETURN ((COMISSAO/TOTAL_SEM_IMPOSTO)*100);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Function call:

```
SELECT 
     COMMISSION_MARGIN(AI.ID) AS "Margin (%)"
FROM
    ACCOUNT_INVOICE AS AI
INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE AS OT ON ......
```

But I receive this message:

```
ERROR:  column "SELECT SUM(ILA.QUANTITY) FROM INVOICE_LINE_AGENT AS ILA
  " doesn't exists
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "commission_margin" line 6 at attribution
```

Comment: You write a string, but don't call the query you write. I'd recommend reading the documentation of functions some more. You have to execute your queries and then grab the results from them. Have a look at some of the other functions here on SO to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `SELECT ... INTO` to put the values that your sql query returns into that variables. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COMMISSION_MARGIN(Aiid NUMERIC) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
    DECLARE
           COMISSAO NUMERIC;
           TOTAL_SEM_IMPOSTO NUMERIC;
    BEGIN
         SELECT SUM(ILA.QUANTITY) INTO COMISSAO 
           FROM INVOICE_LINE_AGENT AS ILA
                INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE_LINE AS AIL 
                        ON ILA.INVOICE_LINE_ID = AIL.ID
                INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE AS AI 
                        ON AI.ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
          WHERE AI.ID = Aiid 
          GROUP BY AI.ID;

          SELECT SUM(ILA.PRICE_SUBTOTAL) INTO TOTAL_SEM_IMPOSTO 
            FROM INVOICE_LINE_AGENT AS ILA
                     INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE_LINE AS AIL 
                             ON ILA.INVOICE_LINE_ID = AIL.ID
                     INNER JOIN ACCOUNT_INVOICE AS AI 
                             ON AI.ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
           WHERE AI.ID = Aiid 
           GROUP BY AI.ID;

         RETURN ((COMISSAO/TOTAL_SEM_IMPOSTO)*100);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As a plus you should consider in reading about exception treatment. Because when you use the `SELECT ... INTO` statements you may encounter some problems as if your query returns more than one rows or no rows at all. See the docs here: [Executing a Query with a Single-Row Result](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Comment: Thank you Jorge, i will try this and let you know if it works there. By the way we both from Brazil. =0)

Answer (score 2):

Largely simplify, don't run two separate queries and just use an SQL function instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COMMISSION_MARGIN(Aiid NUMERIC)
  RETURNS NUMERIC AS
$func$

SELECT (SUM(ILA.QUANTITY) * 100) / SUM(AIL.PRICE_SUBTOTAL)
FROM   INVOICE_LINE_AGENT   ILA
JOIN   ACCOUNT_INVOICE_LINE AIL ON ILA.INVOICE_LINE_ID = AIL.ID
JOIN   ACCOUNT_INVOICE      AI  ON AI.ID = AIL.INVOICE_ID
WHERE  AI.ID = Aiid

$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin. I will also try this one.